# Discord.py if statement emoji not continuing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have a problem, where I have my if statement, which should absolutely work but it does not.

Here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == xxxx:
        print(payload.emoji)
        if payload.emoji == "":
            print('test')
```

So this should work because payload.emoji returns this:

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: `which should absolutely work but it does not`. What do you expect it to do, and what's actually happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add more explanation:
`on_reaction_add` [provides](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_reaction_add#discord.Reaction) a `Reaction` object. `Reaction.emoji` returns the associated `Emoji` object, and the Emoji's Unicode representation can be retrieved with `Emoji.name`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I have just found the error.

You have to write `payload.emoji.name` not `payload.emoji`.

That's all.

Comment: this worked for me. discord.py is strange.